# Can a Noun be an Action?

Tags: verbs, nouns

For example, in the phrase:

> Yodelling is good fun.

'Yodelling' is a noun that refers to an action. Would it be correct to call this noun an action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Yodelling is good fun.*

"Yodelling" is strictly speaking ambiguous between a noun and a verb, though the verb is the more salient interpretation ("to yodel is fun").

Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in *occasional yodelling.*

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, this noun is a [gerund](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/whats-a-gerund/):

> a form of a verb that ends in *-ing* that is used as a noun

Calling it an "action" is sort of ambiguous, and it depends on why you want to use that word.  Yes it's an action in the sense that it's an activity you can perform, but "action" isn't a part-of-speech.

Comment: Why do you think it's ambiguous to call it an action? What do you mean by "action" isn't a part-of-speech?

Comment: I mean that it's not one of [these](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parts-of-speech/).  There are action *verbs* as distinct from linking verbs, but "yodelling" (as you correctly point out) is not a verb in that sentence, it's a noun.  So it depends on why you're using the word "action".  Are you trying to describe actions to someone?  Designing a video game?  Then yes.  Are you diagramming a sentence?  Then no.

Comment: You can't tell whether it's a gerund or not in this sentence. There's not enough information to decide.